# Incorrect syntax near 'tblAPInvSub' in VB.net & SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have this query:

```
Public Sub LoadList(ByVal InvNo As String)
        Dim params As ListDictionary = New ListDictionary
        Dim query As String


        params.Add(_tblAPInvSub.ColumnNames.InvNo, InvNo)

        query = "SELECT tblAPInvSub.InvNo, tblAPInvSub.GLCode,
tblGLAccounts.GLName, tblAPInvSub.SLCode,tblSLAccounts.SLName,
ISNULL(tblAPInvSub.DRAmt,0) AS DRAmt, ISNULL(tblAPInvSub.CRAmt,0) AS
CRAmt, tblAPInvSub.LineID " & _
                "FROM tblAPInvSub INNER JOIN  tblGLAccounts ON
tblAPInvSub.GLCode = tblGLAccounts.GLCode " & _
                "INNER JOIN tblSLAccounts ON tblAPInvSub.SLCode =
tblSLAccounts.SLCode" & _
                "WHERE tblAPInvSub.InvNo = @InvNo "


        LoadFromSql(query, params, CommandType.Text)
    End Sub
```

Of I omit the `where` clause it will work, else it will return the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'tblAPInvSub'

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: there should be a reason for the downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put a space after `tblSLAccounts.SLCode` or before the `WHERE`

Comment: a space before the "?

Comment: Thanks it worked! but may you care to explain why it needs a space? i am used to mysql and php programming. thank you :)

Comment: Either `tblSLAccounts.SLCode " & _` or `" WHERE tblAPInvSub.InvNo = @InvNo "`

Comment: When the string is concatenated, if there is no space it would read `ON tblAPInvSub.SLCode = tblSLAccounts.SLCodeWHERE blAPInvSub.InvNo = @InvNo`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   select * from 
    (
    <your long query what you posted>
    )x
    WHERE tblAPInvSub.InvNo = @InvNo
```